# Why names() returns the names of at least 2 columns in the data.frame in R?

Tags: r, dataframe

I was wondering why `names()` or `colnames()` return the names of ***at least 2*** columns in the `data.frame` in R?

For example, `names(mtcars[, 2])` returns `NULL` but `names(mtcars[, 2:3])`, works perfectly ok (i.e., returns `"cyl"  "disp"`)?

What to do to get the name of a single column in a `data.frame`, then?

Answer (score 2):

The result of `mtcars[,2]` is a vector, not a data.frame (because of the default `drop = TRUE` argument). Use `names(mtcars)[2]` to get one column name.